# How do I use the numericality validator in Rails to validate a number between 2 min max numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am trying to write a rails application the involves geographic lat and long values and I've written a validation for this below:

`validates :latitude, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: -89.9999, less_than_or_equal_to: 89.9999}, allow_nil: true`

Note: latitude and longitude are decimal values with precision: 6 scale: 4 and precision 7 scale: 4 respectively. (Latitude goes from -90 to 90 (exclusive) and longitude goes from -180 to 180 (inclusive))

However, this code is passing -90 and 90 respectively when it should in fact fail. Does numericality validation take more than 1 arguments as used above? How would I write this validation properly?

Thank you.

EDIT: I have taken a look at the documentation for the validator and it only checks for:

`{ :greater_than => :>, :greater_than_or_equal_to => :>=, :equal_to => :==, :less_than => :<, :less_than_or_equal_to => :<=, :odd => :odd?, :even => :even? }`

So I assumed that the way I used it above would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce this problem:

```
# Code

require 'rails'

class Testing
  attr_accessor :number
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :number, numericality: {
    greater_than_or_equal_to: -89.999, less_than_or_equal_to: 89.999
  }
end

[89, 89.999, 90, 90.001].each do |n|
  t = Testing.new
  t.number = n
  puts "#{n} valid: #{t.valid?}"
end

# Output

89 valid: true
89.999 valid: true
90 valid: false
90.001 valid: false
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem, it's my own (stupid) mistake. I've mistakenly swapped the invalid latitudes and longitudes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sometimes knowing that the problem is not where you think it is is enough to kick things in the right direction. :) Glad I helped!